# Android XML web service username and password validation

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically I've not done this before and most of what I've found has not really been specific to me. What I am trying to do is have my Username and Password textfields validated by an external source (in this case SOAP, XML web service). Is there any tutorials specific to online username/password validation for XML/Soap?

Comment: Basically, you have to set up a service that will receive username / password pairs to proceed to the validation and send back the result. But your question is a bit vague and covers several subjects: web services protocols, securing HTTP exchanges, securing the application to avoid this checking to be bypassed... etc. Would you specify a bit more?

Comment: I believe it is a web service protocol. Essentially once the username and password is validated, it will proceed to the next screen and show a specific URL that is attached within the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using KSoap2.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

and:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksoap2